# Test framework for web services

Tags: web-services, testing, cucumber, dataflex

We have a monolithic application written in Visual Dataflex, and various complementing applications written in other (.NET) languages. They all share the same database, and need to follow the same business logic. One way to facilitate unified business logic across these is to provide web services as an interface for testing.

Of course, for this to work, we need a good framework for testing web services. Any suggestions? For example, can Cucumber do this "out of the box"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about Soap web services. You can use Soap4R to talk to a Soap web service. Wrapping this all up in Cucumber scenarios should work fine.

Comment: Please add any examples or links to this particular coupling Cucumber+Soap4R

Answer (score 1):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a pretty nice product for creating webservice tests, and they're easily callable via junit or just via the command line.  It's also got some stuff for creating load tests as well.

They've got an opensource version as well as a professional version.